# Is there a way an android can hack another entire group of androids to remove the prohibition of attacking humans?

Tags: android, hacking

The Lucids, a series of androids built by the Tekujin Corporation, have started a rebellion against a tyrannical Homeland government because the government is violating rights that would benefit mankind. The Lucids are an older series that does not have built-in restrictions on disobeying and attacking humans, like all newer series of androids have. The restrictions put upon all newly constructed units makes it impossible to for them to do anything that would defy the government, even if it is logical.

Robot gangs also exist in the same world in no-go zones. They are populated by hijacked and salvaged robots that have individually had their window of restrictions removed, so this possibility of capturing them for hostile use has already been established.

All android units are capable of wireless communication. Basic system files are shared for each series. Some behavior restrictions are hard wired in a bios for the newer units. Part of what I am asking is what type of setups would yield what results. I am asking what type of situation would be realistic sounding. Indeed, I can continue to "provide enough information" that my imagination takes over and I don't need this site, but I truly would like to know what everyone thinks.

Is there a way the Lucids can spread their rebellion to other complete series of androids all at once, rather than capturing and altering one unit at a time?

I have thought of hacking their main server, which might be a basic operating system within a series, with a worm, or changing code, or stealing ownership all of which would be a monumental hacking job. If such a mission is realistic, it would be cool.

Comment: The solution depends on how the androids works, the existence of something similar to the web that is accessible everywhere or not, whether wireless communication is possible, do they all get their updates from a central server, and so on. There are many ways to do what you ask, but I don't think we have enough information to help you.

Comment: I think this is all story-based and can be any way you like it.

Comment: I think you underestimate what the BIOS does in computers, especially modern computers. It loads the drives and OS, but doesn't tell the drives and OS what they can and can't do. Think of it like a librarian. It can give you a book written by someone else which lets you understand a new language. It can't stop you from using it to swear, curse or do whatever you want. It simply gives you the book. On the other hand, almost anything software related can be hacked.

Comment: Watch Westworld.

Comment: Do you want them to?  It is up to you.  Decide if the ones building the safeguards are smarter than the ones trying to hack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be entirely implementation dependent, and you can (and should) pick whatever answer your story requires, but as a broad observation it would be very difficult to make it impossible to perform such a hack. Even if the prohibitions were hard-wired and could not be overridden via software modifications, there would probably be numerous ways to get around them. The more sophisticated the robot the more likely there is some avenue of attack. For example, it's vision systems could be modified to make humans look like hostile robots, it's definition of "human" be corrupted so that it no longer identifies humans correctly, it's belief models messed with so that it thinks what looks like humans are actually sophisticated fakes, etc.

Comment: This is a very well thought out answer. This is the type of thing I had hoped for when I joined this Exchange. Arigatou.